# How to copy file and folder in NexentaStor

Tags: javascript, fileserver

On Nexenta, if you create folder via APIs it can be displayed on the web admin.
And I need to create folder/file automatically, but I cannot find any API support to do this. [Here is the APIs of Nexenta.](http://docs.nexenta.com/NexentaRH/NexentaRH/server/NXS_v40_en/projects/NXS_Merged_UG_IG/NexentaStor-API.html)
I am using javascript to call Nexenta's APIs, how can I create folder/file or copy from local ( or another location) ?

Comment: Can you confirm that you really mean JavaScript and not Java?

Comment: Yes, I am using Nodejs at server side.

Comment: Anyone can help me? I can create folder via Nexenta's api, but I cannot find any api support to create/write file to Nexenta storage.